# How long does the OS store incomming network traffic before discarding it?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking

> How long does the OS store incomming network traffic before discarding it?

Suppose I have a open socket on some port that are open for incomming packets.

What happens if some other host on the network sends lots of packets to this socket, and the socket does not issue a `read()` call to read this data? Will the OS begin to destroy data in a FIFO-fashion, or will the OS stop accepting (rejecting) the incomming packets?

I've read the OS stores traffic associated with a socket in seperate buffers, i.e. separate incomming/outcomming buffers exist for each (open) socket. Will the above happen, when this buffer is full?

Also, what happens if some host sends packets to a closed socket? Does the OS rejects the packets? Or are they stored temporarily in some buffer?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Flow_control

Comment: You should read the RFC for TCP/UDP.  Why ask here when the information is freely available?  Why ask for it to be pointlessly rewritten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until either the data is read or the local socket is closed.

In the case of TCP that implies advertising a zero send window to the peer when the socket receive buffer is full. A TCP segment that arrives out of order on the other hand may simply be ignored.

In the case of UDP it implies dropping datagrams that arrive after the socket receive buffer has filled.

Comment: So to be sure, in case of TCP the data is not lost, since the receiver will force the sender not to send more until given green light by a window update. However, in case of UDP the data will be LOST, right?

Comment: That's what 'dropping datagrams' means.